# Jquery hover not working in IE / window touch

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, window, touch

If you go to http://www.comc.com/Cards/Baseball/1959/Topps/50/Willie_Mays/1808322/GRADED/PSA/6
and hover on the cards you will see 4 panels shows up. In IE on windows tablet and mobile, the panels shows up but once you tab on it, it seems like trying to select the text and disabled the panel. Below is the code that trigger the panel.

```
 $(".cardImageWrapper").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).children(".detailsPanelWrapper").stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(100);
 }, function(){
    $(this).children(".detailsPanelWrapper").stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(80);
 });
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? or A better solution to solve all similar hover problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I read on windows official site, they says add aria-haspopup="p" to the element that has hover event.

I read somewhere else says aria-haspopup="true" works too. I tested it and it indeed worked.

Comment: brilliant -it took a while for me to look around and find this answer -AFTER I discovered it wasn't the device it was ie and I didn't have to write any new code. I THOUGHT maybe IE would be optimized for win 8  but I thought wrong -even when Microsoft overhauls the OS they still can't get the browser right.